# How to fix this AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'fileno' in Python3.8

Tags: python, python-idle

I am using the [Pick](https://pypi.org/project/pick/) package to create a curses-based interactive selection list in my IDLE terminal. This is the code I currenty have:

```
from pick import pick
title = 'Please choose your favorite programming language: '
options = ['Java', 'JavaScript', 'Python', 'PHP', 'C++', 'Erlang', 'Haskell']
option, index = pick(options, title)
print(option)
print(index)
```

However, I am running into the following error:

```
Python 3.8.5 (tags/v3.8.5:580fbb0, Jul 20 2020, 15:57:54) [MSC v.1924 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license()" for more information.
>>> 
= RESTART: C:\Users\haneg\OneDrive\Documents\Python-Scripts\Restrictieenzymen.py
---
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\haneg\OneDrive\Documents\Python-Scripts\Restrictieenzymen.py", line 5, in <module>
    option, index = pick(options, title)
  File "C:\Users\haneg\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.8_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python38\site-packages\pick\__init__.py", line 195, in pick
    return picker.start()
  File "C:\Users\haneg\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.8_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python38\site-packages\pick\__init__.py", line 181, in start
    return curses.wrapper(self._start)
  File "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.8_3.8.1520.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\lib\curses\__init__.py", line 84, in wrapper
    stdscr = initscr()
  File "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.8_3.8.1520.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\lib\curses\__init__.py", line 30, in initscr
    fd=_sys.__stdout__.fileno())
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'fileno'
```

If I run this code directly in Python, without IDLE, I do not get this error. Does anyone have any suggestions on how to fix this problem? Any help is appreciated!

Comment: I have seen Nonetype no-attribute errors before.  Add the *complete* traceback to your question.  Also, run the same code directly in Python, without IDLE, to tell if IDLE is actually involved.  In a terminal/console: `python <path-to-code-file>`

Comment: Dear Terry, I confirmed that IDLE is involved. If I run it directly on python I don't get the error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IDLE is involved but only as a GUI app not normally started from a command line.

1. The immediate bug is trying to access .fileno without catching the AttributeError and exiting gracefully.  You could mention this to `pick` people.  This situation is not unique to IDLE.
2. The deeper error is trying to run curses in an environment where the error occurs.  The circumstance of sys.**stdxxx** being none in mentioned in the [IDLE doc](https://docs.python.org/3/library/idle.html#running-user-code).  You can fix **this** by starting IDLE in a console with `> python -m idlelib`.  (This should be clearer in the doc.)  When I do so on Windows, I get the expected fileno.

```
    >>> import sys;
    >>> sys.__stderr__.fileno()
    2
```

3. The stdlib curses is documented as Unix-only.  If `pick` runs on Windows, it must include something sufficient for its needs.

---

Running from Command Prompt or PowerShell should suffice for you, but I have two additional ideas to help others in the future.  I am noting this here to not forget.

1. Add a new mechanism to check error class and message.  For this case, ff AttributeError and template matches and object is Nonetype and attribute is std stream attribute, add an IDLE-specific addendum suggesting fixes.
2. Add an option to the newish `Run` => `Run ... customized` menu dialog to run in a system terminal (for those who did not start IDLE in a terminal).  My first attempt at this failed, but this question add another use case.  So I should try again.